# Magnolia get content from children page in freetext

Tags: magnolia

I have a tree structure and want to use this as a category based faq.
I know there is a categorization module, but i want to use a file tree structure.

so i had the following:

```
faq
  - first category
    - first entry
    - second entry
  - second category
    - first entry
  ...
```

each page has an dialog with an headline and a description. thats the content i want to get for each page.

so currently i get the current page, and loop through the childpages

```
[#local currentPage=cmsfn.page(content) /]
[#local pageChildren = cmsfn.children(currentPage,  "mgnl:page")]

[#list pageChildren as page ]
{
    "category": "${page.title}",

    [#local pageContent = cmsfn.contentById(page)]
    "headline": "${pageContent.headline!?json_string}",
    "description": "${pageContent.description!?json_string}"
 } [#if page?has_next],[/#if]
 [/#list]
```

Now i get the category (the page title) for each entry. Thats fine. But headline and description are not filled.

I know, `page` is a node. `page` is the page and can access each page property (title, template).

I didn't find anything to get the content from a page via `cmsfn`. There are methods for `contentById`, `contentByPath` and also `page()` to get the page for a content.

But how i can get the content, from a page?

**Update:**

I made big step.
I get my pageContent from contentByPath, and use here the path of the page.
After this, i convert this to an JCR Node.

```
[#local pageContent = cmsfn.contentByPath(page.@path)]
[#local jcr = cmsfn.asJCRNode(pageContent)]
```

Now dumping shows my jcr.

```
Node (/my-website/faqs/kategorie1/question1)
  footer = Node (/my-website/faqs/kategorie1/question1/footer)
    mgnl:activationStatus = true (Boolean)
    [...]
    jcr:uuid = "a09d13da-3549-4b2a-8609-3b635e6f1c59" (String)
  layers = Node (/my-website/faqs/kategorie1/question1/layers)
    mgnl:activationStatus = true (Boolean)
    [...]
    jcr:uuid = "08b52c64-7327-4300-884c-047e42f560d0" (String)
  overlays = Node (/my-website/faqs/kategorie1/question1/overlays)
    mgnl:activationStatus = true (Boolean)
    [...]
    jcr:uuid = "9a78479b-0d25-4acf-9554-b9d626a7cc61" (String)
  content = Node (/my-website/faqs/kategorie1/question1/content)
    0 = Node (/my-website/faqs/kategorie1/question1/content/0)
      description = "something" (String)
      headline = "my example" (String)
      mgnl:activationStatus = true (Boolean)
      mgnl:created = Jul 24, 2019 11:20:40 AM UTC (Date)
```

What i really need, is here the content node, and the description and the headline.

But how to access this, and are there better methods to get this content?

Answer (score 0):

You've already gotten the title of a page and any other property on the page node behaves just same as the title property. Hence, page.description will give you the description property of the given page node/object.

Let's also clarify what #contentById() method does. It is responsible to fetch a node by its identifier and returns a ContentMap e.g.

```
ContentMap (think as a Node object but mere Map) contentById(String identifierOfRequestedNode)
```

Update:

Via contentById method, you can directly access description and name, you do not need to convert it to the Node object.

E.g.

```
pageContent.description
pageContent.name
```

Hope that helps,

Cheers,

Comment: thanks for your answer. i think i asked a little bit unclear. i update my question.